# All eigenvalues less than 1 in factor analysis

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, eigenvalues

Is it possible to have all eigenvalues less than 1 during factor analysis? then what can be concluded here? since a factor is considered a factor when the eigenvalue of the factor is greater than 1.  Would be appreciated if there is an explanation. Thanks

Comment: This may not be the case in principal component analysis, since the sum of the eigenvalues equals the number of items. However, factor analysis treats part of the variance as random (error) variance and excludes it from the calculation. Therefore, it may happen that even the highest eigenvalue is less than 1, especially if you are working with a small number of not highly correlated items.

Comment: Maybe you are analyzing the covariance matrix instead of the correlation matrix?